# rviz Visualization of Marker Array MD5 sum mismatch

Tags: rviz, octomap, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to play a rosbag with a topic of type visualization_msgs/MarkerArray which represents an occupancy grid. When I replay the bag and try to visualize on rViz, I encounter the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1519233528.633435694]: Client [/rviz_1519232642521321305] wants topic /occupied_cells_vis_array to have datatype/md5sum [visualization_msgs/MarkerArray/d155b9ce5188fbaf89745847fd5882d7], but our version has [visualization_msgs/MarkerArray/90da67007c26525f655c1c269094e39f]. Dropping connection.
```

I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283323/rviz-visualization-of-marker-array-md5-sum-mismatch/) by [PrieureDeSion](https://answers.ros.org/users/33799/prieuredesion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This likely means the bag file was created on a different version of ROS. This could likely be fixed with `rosbag check` and `rosbag fix` http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/migration

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PrieureDeSion](https://answers.ros.org/users/33799/prieuredesion/) on 2018-02-21**:
That fixes it! Thanks a lot @jarvisschultz

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-02-21**:
Great! Glad that sorted you out.